# Image is loaded after the process completion and remains after that

Tags: google-apps-script

My code is below. It will accept data from the input text; then it will fetch the recent newest feed from stackoverflow(based in the input) in google spreadsheet.

I have(wanted) set an external gif image to be shown as a progress indicator while fetching of rss feed and its processing is going on.

Problem is: When i remove the commented part; that gif image will never be visible to the user and when that is remained as a comment; that gif image is being loaded by the app **after the completion of the process and remained then after**.

I want it to be visible only when the process(fetching of rss and processing of it) is going on. So is there any way to make it possible?

```
function stackoverflow(){   
    var app =UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(380).setWidth(800);   
    app.setTitle("Enter tag name");
    var mydoc=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
    var txtBox = app.createTextBox().setFocus(true).setWidth("150").setId("ticker").setName("ticker");
    var mainpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('mainpanel');
    mainpanel.add(txtBox);
    var subbtn = app.createButton("Get posts!").setId("tick").setWidth("80");
    mainpanel.add(subbtn);
    var myloadingimg=app.createImage("http://schedule.msu.edu/img/InProgress.gif").setHeight("26").setWidth("26").setId("loadingimg");
    mainpanel.add(myloadingimg.setVisible(false));
    app.add(mainpanel);
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');    
    var submitHandler = app.createServerHandler("clicker").addCallbackElement(mainpanel);
    subbtn.addClickHandler(submitHandler);
    app.add(panel);
    mydoc.show(app);
}
function clicker(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var txtBox = app.getElementById("ticker");
   app.getElementById("loadingimg").setVisible(true);
   var panel=app.getElementById("panel");
   app.remove(1);
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');    
   var stackurl = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames="+e.parameter.ticker+"&sort=newest";
   var stackXML = UrlFetchApp.fetch(stackurl).getContentText();
   var stackDOC = Xml.parse(stackXML, false);
   var stackentry = stackDOC.getElement().getElements('entry');

   for (var i = 0; i < stackentry.length; i++) {    
       var result = stackentry[i];
       panel.add(app.createHTML("<br><b>Post Title: </b>"+ result.getElement('title').getText()+"<br>"));
       panel.add(app.createAnchor('', '') .setText("Post URL").setHref(result.getElement('link').getAttribute('href').getValue()));       
       panel.add(app.createHTML("<br>"));
      }

   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(760, 280);
   scroll.add(panel);
   app.add(scroll);
   //app.getElementById("loadingimg").setVisible(false);
   return app;
}

function onOpen() 
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name:'stackoverflow',functionName:'stackoverflow'});
  ss.addMenu("f2", menuEntries);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of clientHandlers which are meant for precisely such cases.

```
function stackoverflow(){   
    ...   
    var clientHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(myloadingimg).setVisible(true); 
    var submitHandler = app.createServerHandler("clicker").addCallbackElement(mainpanel);
    subbtn.addClickHandler(submitHandler).addClickHandler(clientHandler); 
    ...
}
function clicker(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   ....
   app.getElementById("loadingimg").setVisible(false);
   return app;
}
```